# R table from SQL weird behavior

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi

I connected R to SQL using the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server", 
                 Server = "srv name", 
                 Database = "Warehouse")
```

I pull in the table I want using

```
data <- tbl(con, in_schema("prc", "PricingLawOfUniv")))
```

The following things show me what I expect to see (a 38 X 1000 table of data):

1. head(*data*)
2. colnames(*data*)

The following things behave as I expect:

1. In the Environment *data* is a "list of 2"
2. View(*data*) shows a list with "src" and "ops" - each of those is also a list of 2.

Ultimately I want to work with the 38 X 1000 table as a dataframe using dplyr. How can I do this? I tried data[1] and data[2] but neither worked. Where is the actual table I want hiding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DBI::Id` to specify the table/schema, and then `dbReadTable`:

```
tbl <- DBI::Id(
  schema  = "prc",
  table   = "PricingLawOfUniv"
)
data <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, tbl)
```

Comment: Tried this and eventually had to force quit :/

Comment: Do you have an estimate of the size on disk of the table you're trying to import?

Comment: rows: 41845983, reserved: 12323592 KB, data: 12253760 KB

Comment: I just found a much smaller table and it worked well. Guess I'll just have to let it run for a while?

Comment: This is ~12Gb, do you have enough RAM on your PC?

Comment: I have 12gb available though I might try subsetting the table before importing it. Stupid question - but how is sql server able to hold such large data sets and query them easily? Is it being served from some massive computer somewhere

Comment: You'll need to use `dbGetQuery` to subset the data before processing it on your PC. SQL server holds this on disk and uses indexes to access specific data ranges quicker. 12 Gb is OK for a database table nowadays.

Comment: My previous company used remote servers or "nodes" when we were working with large data in R. I don't remember explicit sizes, but would that have likely helped with the RAM?

Comment: You could easily find a VM with R and more RAM on the cloud, the problem being to transfer the data.

Comment: WHere would I insert the dbGetQuery function?

Comment: Instead of using `dbReadTable` : `dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE subsetting condition")`

Comment: Does schema.table = tbl in your answer above?

Comment: No, this is `prc.PricingLawOfUnif`. If this doesn't work, I think you can specify the schema in `dbConnect`

Comment: Cool, that did work., Thanks for all the back and forth.. I understand this wasn't a straight forward question

Comment: is it important to close the connection when i am done with gathering tables from sql

Comment: It's better, but it will be done automatically by the Server after a period of inactivity. You can also have a look at the `pool`package [which will handle this for you](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html)